# Unable to reach the link to download the PDF file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, google-colaboratory

I am trying to download multiple pdf files using web scraping (python and selenium on **Google Colab**).
I've logged in and got all the url links successfully but the issue is when I navigate to the url of the pdf file it tooks me to the login page again and when I enter my credencials again it tooks me to the home page instead of the pdf page where I can download it.

This is my code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.offre-emploi.tn/connexion/')

driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'jb_email').send_keys('my_email')
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'jb_password').send_keys('my_password')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'jb_submit_login').click()

driver.get('https://www.offre-emploi.tn/consulter-cv/')
print(driver.title)

time.sleep(1) 

try:
    html = driver.page_source
except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
    html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for pdf in soup.select("a[target='_blank']"):
    filename = pdf['href'][-5:]
    pdf_link = pdf['href'] + ".pdf"
    
    if not("offre-emploi.tn/acces-cv" in pdf_link):
        continue

    driver.get(pdf_link)    
    time.sleep(2)
    pdf_data = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerText;")
    
    print(driver.title)
    # Write the PDF data to a file
    with open(f"resumes/{filename}.pdf", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pdf_data.encode('utf-8'))

driver.quit()
```

Comment: @KJ I see but when I enter the file url in an incognito browser it redirect me to the login page, in this case can I still use the cURL method ?